# pcase matches with rx but not with regex

Tags: regular-expressions, pcase

`(rx bos (1+ (in "0-2")) eos)` evaluates to `` "\\`[0-2]+\\'" ``, so I expected these two functions to be equivalent:

```lisp
(defun with-rx (s)
  (pcase s
    ((rx bos (1+ (in "0-2")) eos) "matched")
    (t "not matched")))

(defun with-regex (s)
  (pcase s
    ("\\`[0-2]+\\'" "matched")
    (t "not matched")))
```

However, it seems that `pcase` treats the `rx` form as a real regexp in the first case and the string as a simple string in the second case:

```
ELISP> (equal (rx bos (1+ (in "0-2")) eos) "\\`[0-2]+\\'")
t
ELISP> (with-rx "01210")
"matched"
ELISP> (with-regex "01210")
"not matched"
```

How come in the `rx` case, `pcase` is smart enough to know that it should treat the `rx` form as a regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rx` pattern is provided by `rx.el` using `pcase-defmacro` (see [code](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-26.2/lisp/emacs-lisp/rx.el#L1183)) . See also [(elisp) Extending pcase](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Extending-pcase.html) on how to add new patterns to the `pcase` macro.